# Click event on bar chart using c3js seems breaking on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying  to bind click event on bars' in bar chart. Its seems working fine in firefox, but breaking in latest chrome browser.

I am getting 
*error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of* undefined

Below is the code snippet that I am using:

```
chart = c3.generate({
                        bindto: "#filterCoverageContainer",
                        data: {
                            onclick: function(d, element) {
                                console.log(d);
                                console.log(element);
                            },
                            columns: [
                                ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                                ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
                            ],
                            type: 'bar',
                        },
                        axis: {
                            x: {
                                type: 'category', // this needed to load string x value
                                label: {
                                    text: 'Filter Names',
                                    position: 'outer-right'
                                }
                            },
                            y: {
                                max: 100,
                                label: {
                                    text: 'Coverage (in %)',
                                    position: 'outer-center'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        grid: {
                            x: {
                                show: true,
                            },
                            y: {
                                show: true
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Please suggest if I am doing it the wrong way or is it something wrong with the library/browser compatibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an issue opened for this error on GitHub.
There is already a fix for this in c3js dev branch which is not merged into master.

Using c3js from dev branch fixed this issue.

Details are on these links:

https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/pull/1564

https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/1566